# Yii2 active record model not saving data

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I've built a simple form model & view, a simple AR model, and a simple controller. The form model assigns the correct values to the AR instance, but when I call save(), none of those values are saved in the DB. Any ideas?

The form model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class PromptForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $intro;
    public $prompt;
    public $notes;
    public $questions;


    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Prompt title',
            'intro' => 'Intro',
            'prompt' => 'Prompt body',
            'notes' => 'Closing notes',
            'questions' => 'Exploration questions',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'prompt'], 'required'],
            ['name', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['name', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['intro', 'prompt', 'notes', 'questions'], 'default'],
        ];
    }

    public function post()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $prompt = new Prompt();
            $prompt->name = $this->name;
            $prompt->intro = $this->intro;
            $prompt->prompt = $this->prompt;
            $prompt->notes = $this->notes;
            $prompt->questions = $this->questions;

            $prompt->author = \Yii::$app->user->getId();

            //die(print_r($prompt, TRUE));

            $prompt->save();

            return $prompt;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The AR model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * Prompt is the model behind the prompt item.
 */
class Prompt extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $name;
    public $intro;
    public $prompt;
    public $notes;
    public $questions;
    public $status;
    public $author;

    public $id;

    /**
     * @return string the name of the table associated with this ActiveRecord class.
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'prompt';
    }

    /**
     * @return array the attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Prompt title',
            'intro' => 'Intro',
            'prompt' => 'Prompt body',
            'notes' => 'Closing notes',
            'questions' => 'Exploration questions',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'author' => 'Author ID',
        ];
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\PromptForm;
use app\models\Prompt;

class PromptsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // Return a list of all prompts:
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionNew()
    {
        if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new PromptForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($prompt = $model->post()) {
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Your prompt was created successfully!');
                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Error while submitting your prompt.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Turns out that if you declare public attributes in your ActiveRecord model, they obscure the automatic attributes that are created by AR. Data gets assigned to your obscuring attributes but doesn't get sent into the database.

The correct AR model should have been simply this:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Prompt extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the name of the table associated with this ActiveRecord class.
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'prompt';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just had the same issue, had me head scratching for a while!

Comment: Hi @Tal V. Please tick it as right answer as it looks like unanswered question.

Comment: Works for me as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Currently forced to use Yii because of Craft CMS. Can't state the framework. So many hidden pitfalls. Extreme lack of Exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$prompt->save(false);
```

If that works that means that some validation rule fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                if ($prompt = $model->post()) {
                    $model->save()
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Your prompt was created successfully!');
                    return $this->goHome();
                } else {
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Error while submitting your prompt.');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sorry, $model does not extend Active Record and so doesn't have a save() method. $model is the form model for my prompt. Its post() method invokes save() on the AR model, but that save doesn't work right for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, change your if condition as follow :

```
if ($prompt = $model->post() !== null) {
```

This will validate that the value which is return is not null.
Your current validation condition is only validating where value is get assigned to variable $prompt or not. And that's why it's always returns true.

Comment: It returns true because a Prompt object is created all right and a data row is created in the database. The only problem is, that data row contains only default data, none of the values I'm trying to feed it.

Comment: Prompt Object is created all right, but it's created in wrong place. Have you aver check any condition with a single equal to sign(=)? Any condition with = sign will always returns true. In this case the condition will form like `$prompt = null` or will form like `$prompt = <object>`, which any way will return true. And you are also telling that you are not feeding values, then What is this for? ` $prompt = new Prompt();
            $prompt->name = $this->name;
            $prompt->intro = $this->intro;
            $prompt->prompt = $this->prompt;`  You are assigning value to it's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same problem recently, when I combine the Active Record class with The Model class. Cause I know that AR actually extends Model in Yii2. Why not write less code.So I move the code from the Model to the AR.

```
$model = new User();  
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

But the AR's _attribute didn't get the post data in the form. the form data is actually in a Model object.

> object(app\models\User)#39 (12) { ["password"]=> string(6) "google"
>   ["newpass"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(5) "Jane1" ["email"]=> string(16)
>   "jane@outlook.com" ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
>   array(2) { ["password_hash"]=> string(60)
>   "$2y$13$.vNKpmosLjW/oYAhIezOZOj8rIG6QJvQj8tGHN2x78.75poXVn6Yi"
>   ["auth_key"]=> string(32) "4XggNakVd-oeU28ny7obdw7gOmZJ-Rbu" }

simply delete the public attribute you want mass assign to the AR instance will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

For who is struggling with this problem, I would remember to check the `beforeSave` method, if present. I mistakenly commented out the `return` statement.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    // never toggle comment on this!!!
    return parent::beforeSave( $insert); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to Troubleshoot**

First thing you should add while developing to your `_form.php` is errorSummary():

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
// Some input fields
...
<?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?> // <--- Add this 
...
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**Simplify**

Why not use scenarios instead if there is some minimal variation form to form:

In your model:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['field_1'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_ADD],  // only on add
            [['field_2'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_UPDATE], // only on update
            [['field_3', 'field_4'], 'required'], // required all the time
        ];
    }
```

In your controller:

```
public function actionAdd()
{
    $model = new Model();
    $model->scenario = Model::SCENARIO_ADD;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('add', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

**Behaviors**

Alternatively, rather than assign the user directly in your model, you could use a behavior like so:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => \yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior::className(),
            'value' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username,
        ],
        [
            'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'sammaye\audittrail\LoggableBehavior',
            'userAttribute' => 'updated_by', //blameable attribute of the current model.
            'ignored' => ['updated_by', 'updated_at'], // This ignores fields from a selection of all fields, not needed with allowed
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: The whole "What Not To Do" section is completely incorrect IMO. Creating separate models for forms is much more readable and more strict with SRP, and it should be preferred (unless you have really simple CRUD). And accessing `Yii::$app->user->identity->username` from model is anti-pattern - although it is simple and works for comon cases, it is not right thing way to do - model should not behave in such way.

Comment: @rob006 I am willing to revise, but let us discuss it out to compose the best answer. It seems unnecessary to build code that already exists in the ActiveRecord class, i.e. load, validate and save. Generally, this is done in the controller with yii in one line: 
`if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->product_id_pk]);
        }`
So how is adding an extended class better then using model scenerios?
Also, I understand your opinion on the anti-pattern, how does the seperate model solve that?

Comment: Separate model allows you to focus on specific context - you have much smaller and simpler model for this particular form, and your main AR model is also simpler, because it is not bloated by code specific for this one form. It is really important in big applications, where AR model easily becomes really fat and hard to maintain. Removing form handling from AR is one of steps to make it simpler and easier to maintain. There are some cases when you can ignore it and handle form in AR model, but creating separate model is usually better way (although it requires more code).

Comment: You can actually read about it in best practices in guide (although they recommend solving this by inheritance, which is IMO less clean than separate model): https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#best-practices

Comment: I see no reason why it should not be assigned in this way. Except that model should not access `Yii::$app->user->getId()` directly - it should be passed from controller to form model.