# yii2 not saving all fields

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I have this User model:

```
  public $id;
    public $username;
    public $name;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;
```

and this Form model

```
  class SignupForm extends Model

{
    public $username;
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $fio;
    public $phone;
```

And I try to save:

```
$user = new User();
            $user->username = $this->username;
            $user->name = $this->name;
            $user->email = $this->email;
            var_dump($this->username);
            var_dump($user->username);
            var_dump($this->name);
            var_dump($user->name);

            $user->save(false);
```

But in the database table this only saves the email field. All data in `var_dump` are correct.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827002/yii2-active-record-model-not-saving-data):

> Turns out that if you declare public attributes in your ActiveRecord
>   model, they obscure the automatic attributes that are created by AR.
>   Data gets assigned to your obscuring attributes but doesn't get sent
>   into the database.

You can also use the model's `attributes()` function to declare your model fields, and set validation on the fields using the `rules()` function.

Example:

```
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'id',
        'username',
        'name',
        'email',
    ];
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['id', 'safe'],
        [['username', 'name', 'email'], 'required'],
        [['username', 'name', 'email'], 'string'],
    ];
}
```

For more information and examples, please check out the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation)